# How do I make my floating shelf stronger/less susceptible to vibrations?

Tags: structural, construction, engineering

I'm building an entertainment center. I plan to put a turntable on the middle shelf in the picture below. There will be a floor standing speaker directly below the shelf. I expect the bass from the music to cause the shelf to slightly vibrate. What can I do to reduce the amount of vibration that occurs on that middle shelf? I'm worried the vibrating will damage the records and/or distort the sound.

As you can see, I've already added an extra 2x4 on the top and bottom of the shelf, but I'm not sure that will actually help (I'd add more if I knew it would help). Do I have any other options? I'd like to keep the floating look so I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve running chains/wire from above the shelf out to the lip of the shelf. Once I start putting reclaimed wood on the frame, there's no going back - that's why I'm asking now. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You mainly need to stiffen the shelf itself - so the thicker the better, or construct each shelf as a box around a frame made of something stiff but light - extruded aluminium would be ideal. This only hints at the *how* aspect though.

Comment: i agree, thicker shelf,  i would use butcher block. also make sure the new wall is very securely attached to the framing of the old wall.  You could actually open the the old wall and frame in  another slot inline for the floating shelf there by adding much more strength for the cantilevered shelf.

Comment: It might help to put a rubber mat between the shelf and the turntable to isolate the turntable from vibrations. Making things really solid will only help to transmit vibrations (speaker->floor->wall->shelf).

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I was already leaning towards the rubber mat idea, so I'll go that route. Just wanted to make sure there wasn't something else simple I could do before sealing it up.